# Linq to Entities: How do I pass an IQueryable to a Method

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, iqueryable

I am really baffled on this one. I am trying to pass my **posts** vaiable to a method. How do I go about doing this:

```
var posts = from p in context.post
            where (p.post_isdeleted == false && (object.Equals(p.post_parentid, null))
            select new
            {
                p.post_date,
                p.post_id,
                FavoriteCount = (from f in context.favorites
                                 where f.post.post_id == p.post_id
                                 select new { f }).Count()
            };


posts = QuestionList.FilterQuestion(posts, sort);

//the problem is here
//IQueryable is not the right type for posts. What type do I put in there
private static IQueryable FilterQuestion(IQueryable p, string sort)
{
```

Comment: Linq query could probably be simplified somewhat.  For example, `FavoriteCount = p.post.favorites.count()` if your object model is set up properly.

Answer (score 2):

```
private static IQueryable<post> FilterQuestion(IQueryable<post> p, string sort)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with anonymous objects (the `select new { }`).  You'll have to specify a strong type in there, like:

```
var posts = from p in context.post
        where (p.post_isdeleted == false && (object.Equals(p.post_parentid, null))
        select new Post
        {
            Date = p.post_date,
            Id = p.post_id,
            FavoriteCount = (from f in context.favorites
                             where f.post.post_id == p.post_id
                             select new { f }).Count()
        };
```

From here, you can use @Luhmann's answer and strongly-type IQueryable.